# Three asterisks in echo output inserting listing?

Tags: bash, shell, osx-elcapitan

Can anyone tell me why the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST=$(echo '*** this is a test ***')
echo $TEST
```

...outputs a listing of the current directory, then "this is a test", then another listing of the current directory?

Background: I have some output that I'm putting in a variable, and then I want to do several different greps on the contents of that variable, but the echo is inserting all this extra stuff that shouldn't be there.

This is on OS X 10.11.4.

Answer (score 2):

globbing in action!  `*` expands in the second echo.  You have to double quote it to prevent expansion.

```
echo "$TEST"
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126020/1435869) for a related answer