# Wildcard within quotations

Tags: bash, glob

When I do the following:

```
rmdir /path/to/dir/*.lproj
```

it works fine.

When I do:

```
APP_RESOURCES="/path/to/dir"
rmdir "$APP_RESOURCES/*.lproj"
```

It doesn't work and says it literally looks for a directory named with an astrix-symbol. The wildcard doesn't get interpreted. How can this be made to work within quotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expansion is handled by the shell so you will have to write something like this:

```
APP_RESOURCES="/path/to/dir"
rmdir "${APP_RESOURCES}/"*.lproj
```

Answer (score 4):

No globbing is done inside double quotes. Do

```
APP_RESOURCES="/path/to/dir"
rmdir "$APP_RESOURCES"/*.lproj
```

See this [[ question ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885461/assumption-with-double-quotes-single-quotes-no-quotes) for some detail.

Answer (score 3):

You are quoting your variable expansions, keep doing that. Bad thing is that you try to quote your globbing. For the shell to glob you shouldn't quote:

```
app_resource="/path/to/dir"
rmdir "$app_resource"/*.lproj
```

This will however still expand to `/path/to/dir/*.lproj` in cases where no match is found, consider this:

```
% app_resource="/path/to/dir"
% echo "$app_resource/something/that/doesnt/exists/"*.abc
/path/to/dir/something/that/doesnt/exists/*.abc
```

One way around that is to check if the file/directory exists:

```
app_resource="/path/to/dir"
dir_to_remove="$app_resource/"*.lproj
[ -d "$dir_to_remove" ] && rmdir "$dir_to_remove"
```