# Bash Parameter Expansion - get part of directory path

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

Lets say I have this variable

```
FILE=/data/tenant/dummy/TEST/logs/2020-02-03_16.20-LSTRM.log
```

I'm trying to get the name of the 4th sub directory, in this example TEST

```
job=${FILE%/*/*}   # This gives me /data/tenant/dummy/TEST
```

Then

```
name=${job##*/}
```

This give me exactly what I want - `Test`

However when I try to use this in for loop like this:

```
for FILE in "/data/tenant/dummy/*/logs/*$year-*"; do
  job=${FILE%/*/*}
  echo $job    # /data/tenant/dummy/TEST(and few other directories, so far so good)
  name=${job##*/} 
  echo $name  
done
```

The result of `echo $name` shows the list of files in my current directory I'm in instead of `TEST`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wildcard within quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563513/wildcard-within-quotations). Take a look at [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is the double quotes groups all files into a single long string:

```
for FILE in "/data/tenant/dummy/*/logs/*$year-*"
```

You can see this if you do something like:

```
for FILE in "/data/tenant/dummy/*/logs/*$year-*"
do
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "${FILE}"
done
```

This should print `++++++++++++++` once followed by a single line with a long list of file names.

To process the files individually remove the double quotes, eg:

```
for FILE in /data/tenant/dummy/*/logs/*$year-*
```

It's also good practice to wrap individual variable references in double quotes, eg:

```
job="${FILE%/*/*}"
echo "$job"
name="${job##*/}"
echo "$name"
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Also tangentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization